# comparing string with enumeration

Tags: java

I am analyzing the following piece of code using a static analysis tool called FindBugs.

```
if(str.equals(enum.SOMEVALUE)) {// do something};
```

where str is a String and enum is an enumeration. The tool generates the following warning for this code, and states

> This method calls equals(Object) on two references of different class types with no common subclasses. According to the contract of equals(), objects of different classes should always compare as unequal; therefore, according to the contract defined by java.lang.Object.equals(Object), the result of this comparison will always be false at runtime.

if I replace the above line of code with this:

```
if(str.equals(enum.SOMEVALUE.toString())) {// do something};
```

then the warning disappears.But I am not sure if the warning that the tool generates is really true and whether I am fixing it the right way ? because I've seen such comparisons before and it appears to be working correctly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your first comparison is basically **wrong**. You are comparing objects of completely different types (`String` and `Enum`) and they can never be equal. [intellij](/questions/tagged/intellij) even gives me a warning here. It compiles only because `equals()` accepts `Object`, not a `String`.

The second comparison is **correct**.

Although [JavaDoc is a bit harsh on `name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) method, I would actually advice using it in case given enum has `toString()` overriden:

```
if(str.equals(FooEnum.SOMEVALUE.name()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice to using name(), making my current approach of an id field in similar situations obsolete.

Comment: Note that objects of different types are definitely allowed to be equal according to equals().  Both FindBugs and IntelliJ are wrong.  There is even an example in the standard java API where this is done: implementations of the List interface implement equals by comparing the elements, even for different subclasses of List.

Comment: @herman: you are right, but `equals()` has to be *symmetrics*, which is easily done with `List` implementations (they are all based on `AbstractList`) but not in OP case.

Answer (score 3):

I think replacing the constant for the `toString()` may be the right thing to do, I would change it for `.name()` though because toString is to be overriden.

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```
enum.SOMEVALUE.name()
```

as it

> Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using:

```
if (SomeEnum.SOMEVALUE == SomeEnum.valueOf(str)) {

}
```

Comment: Note that this will throw an exception if `str` does not represent any `SomeEnum` value

Comment: this would be helpful to use in switch statements

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you are in the right path.

```
if(str.equals(enum.SOMEVALUE.toString())) {// do something};
```

This should be okay.