# Take an array of values and compare them to Enum values in java

Tags: java, string, enums

So what I am trying to do in JAVA is take in a set of values and then compare those values against the same category of values in an Enum so I can find a specific enum.

In other words I have a bunch of Enums

```
public enum Fruits{ 
     APPLE("Red", "Round", "Fruit", true),
     //about 20 or so more Constants
     ORANGE("Orange","Sphere","Citrus", true);

     private String color;
     private String shape;
     private String category;
     private boolean edible;

private Fruits(String color, String shape, String category, boolean edible){
     this.color = color;
     this.shape = shape;
     this.category = category;
     this.edible = edible;
}

//getter methods for each variable
}
```

Now I have an array of strings

```
String[] myStringArray = {"Blue", "Oblong", "Berry"};
String[] myStringArrayTwo = {"Red", "Round", "Fruit"};
```

how could I compare my String Arrays to the String values in the enums so I can figure out which enum Constant my String Array Represents.

In Reality I have a class that reads in these string values from a file into an array and then I want to assign an enum to the class so I can give it a predefined classification that can be used by other classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare string to enum type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682553/how-to-compare-string-to-enum-type-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553649/comparing-string-with-enumeration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(note: the constructor needs not be `private` -- it is by default for enums)

You could code a method in the enum such as:

```
public static findByCharacteristics(final String[] characteristics)
{
    for (final Fruits candidate: values())
        if (candidate.color.equals(characteristics[0])
            && candidate.shape.equals(characteristics[1])
            && candidate.category.equals(characteristics[2]))
            return candidate:
    return null;
}
```

Then you would:

```
final Fruits f = Fruits.findByCharacteristics(theArray);
// check whether f is null; if not, you have a match
```

However, imho, the code "smells"; you should try a different approach. One such "smell" is that the method above requires an array with at least three elements.

Comment: Thanks and you were right the code was pretty nasty. In the end I switched to a Hashmap after some more research and learning. Being new to Java I figured out that Enum's weren't the best approach in this case.